# Working to make a functioning button that relies on site data and interacts with the user's input

Tags: html, css

I'm working with the data and constraints of Toyhouse (Lame, I'm aware haha, but I'm stretching my web design wings here) I don't have much of an actual example because I haven't made any headway with this issue, but I want to have a fully customized sidebar (that I build myself) and I need help getting the favorites button to work. I've been looking at the site elements and such, but I don't have much to go with or know where to really start, all the places I've prodded have been dead ends.

I'll provide what I can find in the elements and such, I'll admit I'm not super familiar with css or HTML and I'm nearly 100% self-taught so please be gentle and if it's glaringly obvious and easy, I'm sorry haha. The code I wrote by hand is also very, very messy and disorganized, so I apologize if that pops up.

If I need to pull anything else from the elements please let me know, and where I might find it. The CSS elements haven't provided to be super useful and I cannot, for the life of me, figure out why the data isn't connecting on my homemade sidebar.

[This](https://toyhou.se/20673245.minnow#)is the toyhouse page I'm working on/with. I'm sorry for the large blurb and weird request, I just have hit so many walls I'm ready to give up at this point haha, and I feel like knowing this will help me move along with my possible web development future, and I just really enjoy doing this kind of stuff so I figured reaching out can't hurt worse than the hours of brick walls I've already hit do.

Thank you thoroughly again, and please let me know if I need to add anything or specify anything, this is my first post here as well, I really just didn't know where else to turn (other users on the site just want me to fiddle with the already existing sidebar and I've put hours into that page for this one little hiccup to force me into hours more of trying to headache that out).

This is the base HTML the site uses for the actual favorites button. If you need any other HTML snippits or anything else off the site please tell me so I can retrieve them!

```
<li class="sidebar-li-favorites hide" data-id="character-20673245" data-url="https://toyhou.se/20673245.minnow/unfavorite" th-favorite="0" data-trigger="focus" tabindex="-1">
<a href="#" class="favorited">
<i class="fa fa-star fa-fw sidebar-icon"></i>Unfavorite
<span class="pull-right sidebar-stat sidebar-stat-favorites th-favorite-count" data-id="character-20673245">0</span>
</a>
</li>

<li class="sidebar-li-favorites" data-id="character-20673245" data-url="https://toyhou.se/20673245.minnow/favorite" th-favorite="1">
<a href="#">
<i class="far fa-star fa-fw sidebar-icon"></i>Favorite
<span class="pull-right sidebar-stat sidebar-stat-favorites th-favorite-count" data-id="character-20673245">0</span>
</a>
</li>
```

I've already tried replacing my little favorite link with what was in the inspection HTML but it did nothing other than create non-working links. I've also tried to manipulate the sidebar stats and CSS and nothing has worked so far, so I feel like I'm missing something that's either so subtle that I can't see it or just obvious and me being self-taught made me overlook it. I again, appreciate any and all help.

Comment: Please read [ask]. You've presented us with a wall of text, but most of it is about your life story instead of the problem. After reading it twice I still can't tell what you want to acheive or what you actually tried.

Comment: Where can you find a working favourite link? I think it uses JavaScript to fetch user data.